# Greasemonkey Script to Change img tag with a applet tag

Tags: java, javascript, applet, greasemonkey

I have tried all the combinations in my little OOP brain of trying to figure out how to use Greasemonkey to replace a < img > tag with a < applet > tag.

There is a little logo down at the bottom of a webpage and I am trying to make a little animation with JAVA depending on some variables. I can get it above and below where I need it to be but I can't seem to replace the whole tag. I have replaced the img with another one, but I can't figure out how to change to a different tag.

I think I have figured out about 40 ways not to do it. I don't know javascript well, I'm in the Dark!

Comment: I thought it wise to add the javascript tag since this would have to be done using js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .replaceChild(oldChild, newChild) method, from the parent Node.

E.g. html:

```
<div>
  <img src="myimage.jpg" id="replaceMe">
</div>
```

greasemonkey:

```
var image = document.getElementById("replaceMe");
var myApplet = //however you're creating your applet Element

image.parent.replaceChild(image, myapplet);
```